# Squashing all git commits into one and signing it

Tags: git, github

I'm quite new to git and I created a pull request for a repo which needs all my commits to be signed. I forked the repo earlier and created a branch that contains my work. As I have ~100 commmits, I'll prefer not to have to edit each one from "pick" to "squash" using git rebase. Also it seems, there's no way to sign the final squashed commit using that.

So, is there a way to-
1) sign all my commits?
OR
2) squash all commits into one and sign that one?

I appreciate any help/suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the `--squash` option for `git merge`.  Then you can sign your work with a new commit message.

> Produce the working tree and index state as if a real merge happened (except for the merge information), but do not actually make a commit, move the HEAD, or record $GIT_DIR/MERGE_HEAD (to cause the next git commit command to create a merge commit). This allows you to create a single commit on top of the current branch whose effect is the same as merging another branch (or more in case of an octopus).

It's non-interactive, so you won't have to go through each commit and pick the squash option as with `git rebase -i`.

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using a decent text editor, which when using `git rebase -i` will let you block select all the lines after the first to replace the action with "f" for squash. Problem solved.

In many editors on Windows, block select is `Alt-drag`.

Then, the standard git reference gives you a good tutorial/walkthrough on signing your commits here:

https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Signing-Your-Work

Comment: I'm fine with editing all the commits but how do I sign that single squashed comment?

Comment: Answer edited - the git book explains this far more comprehensively than I should...